# Error message when doing unit test in flutter

Tags: flutter, unit-testing

I am a beginer in flutter and I have to write some unit test for a project but I get an error and can't find the solution to solve it.

Here is the function that I want to test:

```
  addUser(name, password) async{
    if (name.toString().isEmpty || password.toString().isEmpty) {
      return "Error";
    }
    return await dio.post('https://test.test.com/adduser',
    data: {"name": name, "password": password},
    options: Options(contentType: Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType));
  }
```

Here is the test code:

```
void main() {
  test('Empty field', () {
    var auth = AuthService();
    String result = auth.addUser("", "");
    expect(result, "Error");
  });
}
```

And I get this error:

```
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
test\widget_test.dart 17:18  main.<fn>
```

Can someone help to find where I made a mistake please ? Thanks for yours answers.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question. Please [edit] your question and copy-paste them into the question itself instead of the images. You can format it between ``` <code/data/errors> ```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a missing `await` in the `auth.addUser` call and also a missing `async` in the test function.

It should look like this:

```dart
void main() {
  text('Emtpy field', () async {                // <- Here
    var auth = AuthService();
    String result = await auth.addUser("", ""); // <- Here
    expect(result, "Error");
  });
}
```

Comment: It works ! thank you so mush for your answer !

Comment: Nice to know! If it really works, then please check the accepted answer ✅ right below the up/down (▲, ▼) vote buttons. This way other users would easily verify the correct answer.